# How can a light client be certain he got all relevant transactions?

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, security

With merkle trees, a light client can be sure some transactions he receives are correct with a minimal amount of the blockchain data. How can such a client, though, be sure he received *all* the relevant transactions from/to his address, in order to know his full balance? What if his peer censured some transactions for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't. However, it is sufficient to request the information from a single honest peer, as the proof does work in the other direction.

This is one of the major drawbacks of using [BIP37](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0037.mediawiki) for learning about transactions (other downsides include [terrible privacy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HScK4pkDNds) and high load on the servers you're fetching from).

Several proposals exist to improve this, including [Committed Bloom Filter](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2016-May/012636.html) and committed adress-indexed UTXO sets. None of them have been implemented, however.